# PHP Session not loading

Tags: php, session

On every page load I see the session cookie's value is changing so it is creating a new session every time. All I'm doing is `session_start()` and set some sample test data, without any configuration myself, using default values from `php.ini`.

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "C:\xampp\tmp"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
```

In `C:\xampp\tmp` I observe new session files appearing with every page load, and when opened I see that the data I set is inside. So the problem is, I guess, with recognizing previously created session files. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

## EDIT:

The data I set is just to see if the session is working

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['test'])){
    $_SESSION['test']++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you load the page once and then reload the page, is there still a cookie stored for the session within your browser?  Without the cookie persisting, it will create this behavior

Comment: is it possible you disabled cookies/some sort of development mode is active? try the same operation with another browser and see if the result is the same.

Comment: @Coulton if I delete the cookie manually and delete all session files in `tmp` and open the page as if it were the first time, I see the cookie is set as well as a session file generated in `tmp` holding the test data. However when I refresh the page right away the cookie's value changes and a new session file is generated in `tmp`

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon I hadn't thought of that. I just tried it and the result is the same, new session on every refresh.

Comment: lol sorry, I'm losing my thread.  :|

Comment: @Coulton Just to let you know, if you're curious. I found the cause. I have custom cookie handling in my environment which is executed before `session_start()` and it was setting `$_COOKIE = array()`. Apparently `session_start()` uses `$_COOKIE` to get the id by default so I had to provide it with `session_id()`.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it... might be worth posting that as the answer and accepting it a bit down the line. You might save someone some head scratching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework I'm working with has a custom cookie handling mechanism that loads cookies into a static class and empties `$_COOKIE`. Apparently `session_start()` relies on `$_COOKIE` to retrieve the session id by default, so what I had to do is provide the session id from the cookies class

```
session_id(\Cookie::get('PHPSESSID'));
session_start();
```